# Problem regarding Bregman Divergence of convex function

Tags: functions, derivatives, convex-analysis, divergence-operator

By Bregman Divergence, if $F$ is a convex function, then we can define :

$$D(x,y) = F(y) - F(x) - (y - x) F^{'}(x),$$

whereby, $D(x,y) \ge 0.$

Here, $F{'}(x)$ is the derivative of the function $F$ at $x$.

My question is, do $D(x,y)$ and $D(x^A,y^A)$ have a one-to-one correspondence, where $A \ge 1, A \in \mathrm{R} \;\;\;$ ($\mathrm{R}$ being the real number line) ?

**Here, $x$ and $y$ are scalar variables and $A$ is a scalar constant.**

Comment: What do you mean by $x^A$, for a vector $x$ and a scalar $A$ ? Also for defining Bregman divergence, you don't need the function $F$ to be convex. You need it to be continuously diff'ble on a closed convex domain.

Comment: Here, $x$ is a scalar variable and $A$ is a scalar constant.

Comment: Are you asking whether the function $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, $A \mapsto D(x^A, x^A)$ is injective ? This makes no sense. What if $x = -1$ and $A=1/2$, what do you mean by $D(\sqrt{-1}, \sqrt{-1})$ ? What's the domain of definition of $F$ ? I suspect you'll need to iterate fixing your question multiple times before it becomes reasonable enough (well-formed). Why don't you tell us what you're trying to do precisely.